# Spring Rest Client - Deserializing without wrapper classes

Tags: spring-mvc, jackson, jackson-databind

In my java application, I have to call a remote graphql application.
The response is like this.

```
{
   "data": {
      "response": {
         "product": {
            "id": "...",
            "description": "..."
         }
      }
   }
}
```

I am interested only in this object and deserialize this as `Product.class`

```
{
   "id": "...",
   "description": "..."
}
```

How to use ***spring rest client*** to deserialize this response as `Product`? I do not like to create unnecessary wrapper objects.